# Collision detection with duplicated picturebox

Tags: c#, duplicates, collision, picturebox, detection

For my school I have to do a little project.
The aim of the project is to do a game which spawns different rectangles and you have to click them.

If you click them you recive points and the rectangle gets replaced with a new one.
And every timer tick the box gets bigger.

We have to use pictureboxes.

Now my question is:

How can I make a detection to indicate a picturebox which colides with the panel-border or with a other picture box.

The problem is, that the picboxes are getting duplicated.

So how can I solve this problem?

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BoxClicker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private Random rndColor = new Random();
        private Random rndCreation = new Random();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CreateBox()
        {
            PictureBox gamebox = new PictureBox();
            gamebox.Size = new Size(20, 20);
            gamebox.Location = new Point(rndCreation.Next(0, pnlSpiel.Width - 30), rndCreation.Next(0, pnlSpiel.Height - 30));
            gamebox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rndCreation.Next(0, 255), rndCreation.Next(0, 255), rndCreation.Next(0, 255));
            pnlSpiel.Controls.Add(gamebox);
            gamebox.Click += pictureBox1_Click;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numValues.Value; i++)
            {
                CreateBox();
            }

            tmrResize.Start();

            txtNotification.Text = "Klicke auf die erscheinenden Boxen um Punkte zu sammeln!";
            btnStart.Visible = false;
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateBox();

            PictureBox gamebox = sender as PictureBox;
            int addPoints = gamebox.Width;
            txtPoints.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtPoints.Text) + addPoints).ToString();
            if ((Convert.ToInt32(txtBiggestBox.Text) < addPoints))
            {
                txtBiggestBox.Text = (Convert.ToString(addPoints));
            }
            pnlSpiel.Controls.Remove(sender as PictureBox);
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (tmrEasterEgg.Enabled)
            {
                tmrEasterEgg.Stop();
                BackColor = Color.LightGray;
            }
            else
            {
                tmrEasterEgg.Start();
            }
        }

        private void tmrEasterEgg_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Color randomColor = Color.FromArgb(rndColor.Next(256), rndColor.Next(256), rndColor.Next(256));
            BackColor = randomColor;
        }

        private void tmrResize_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pnlSpiel.Controls.Count; i++)
            {
                PictureBox gamebox = pnlSpiel.Controls[i] as PictureBox;
                gamebox.Size = new Size(gamebox.Size.Width + 1, gamebox.Size.Height + 1);
            }
        }

        private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlSpiel.Controls.Clear();
            txtNotification.Text = "Das Spiel wurde zurückgesetzt";
            txtPoints.Text = "0";
            btnStart.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the collision detection in your `CreateBox` method. And decide whether to add the object or not in there.
Like this:

```
private void CreateBox()
{
    Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(rndCreation.Next(0, pnlSpiel.Width - 30),
        rndCreation.Next(0, pnlSpiel.Height - 30),
        20, 20);

    bool pBDoIntersect = false;
    foreach (Control picturebox in pnlSpiel.Controls)
    {
        if (bounds.IntersectsWith(picturebox.Bounds))
        {
            pBDoIntersect = true;
        }
    }

    if (!pBDoIntersect)
    {
        PictureBox gamebox = new PictureBox();
        gamebox.Size = new Size(bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
        gamebox.Location = new Point(bounds.X, bounds.Y);
        gamebox.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(rndCreation.Next(0, 255), rndCreation.Next(0, 255), rndCreation.Next(0, 255));
        pnlSpiel.Controls.Add(PB);
        gamebox.Click += pictureBox1_Click;
    }
    else
    {
        // spawn in another place?
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. But I think you didn't understood my question. The aim is not, that they can't spawn into each other. My problem is, that I have to make a code, which detects when the box collides with a other box. Because the boxes grow bigger every timer tick. So I have to make a detection to make for "txtNotification" a notification when the boxes collides into each other while they growing. Do you understand me? But I will implement your code anyways because it is useful too. Thanks a lot

Comment: I think I understand you, if you want to add a text to a textfield, when the box collides, you can add that code into `if(pBDoIntersect)`

Comment: I did it in the way you talked about. I inserted the following code to the CreateBox method: `if (pBDoIntersect)
            {
                txtNotification.Text = "Die Boxen sind kollidiert";
            }` But in this way it only gets the text message, when a box gets spawned in a other box I think. And that is not the thing I want. It should get the message when they collide while booth boxes are in the "growing phase". [Link to Screenshot](https://prnt.sc/13ftxza) Here you can see, that it has not the message (on top) while they colliding.

Comment: Update: I found out, that the `if(pBDoIntersect)` only works when a picturebox spawns outside the "gamepanel" but this isn't what I want... I think there is something to change in this section: `bool pBDoIntersect = false;
            foreach (Control picturebox in pnlSpiel.Controls)
            {
                if (bounds.IntersectsWith(picturebox.Bounds))
                {
                    pBDoIntersect = true;
                }
            }` But what have I to change there, that it works with other pictureboxes and not with the panel?